# autowired @components null in unit test

Tags: spring, junit, junit4, spring-framework-beans

I have a class:

```
@Component
public class B {
    @Autowired
    private A a; 
}
```

and A is a component:

```
@Component
public class A{}
```

In unit test class BTest:

```
public class BTest {
    @Test
    public void testBMethod() {
    }
}
```

I am not using an xml to define context or for beans to be picked from.

What is the cleanest way I can get the test to run?

Comment: Use constructor injection and just create the classes as normal with mocks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Spring for the unit tests. **Mockito** may be used for this.

```
public class BTest {
    @Mock
    private A a;

    @Mock
    private B b;

    @Test
    public void testBMethod() {
    }
}
```

For more details, you may check https://springframework.guru/mocking-unit-tests-mockito/
and https://dzone.com/articles/use-mockito-mock-autowired